# How do I allow only the latest inputs to be saved - Python

Tags: python

How do I implement a simple code that will only save the student's latest 3 scores? If the test is repeated later, the old score should be replaced.

Thank you.

This is the code that asks the user the questions and saves the results in the txt. files.

```
import random
import math
import operator as op

correct_answers = 0

def test():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)

ops = {
    '+': op.add,
    '-': op.sub,
    '*': op.mul,
}

keys = list(ops.keys()) 
rand_key = random.choice(keys)  
operation = ops[rand_key]  

correct_result = operation(num1, num2)

print ("What is {} {} {}?".format(num1, rand_key, num2))
user_answer= int(input("Your answer: "))

if user_answer != correct_result:
    print ("Incorrect. The right answer is {}".format(correct_result))
    return False
else:
    print("Correct!")
    return True

username = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hi {}! Welcome to the Arithmetic quiz...".format(username))
class_name = input("Are you in class 1, 2 or 3? ")
correct_answers = 0
num_questions = 10

for i in range(num_questions):
    if test():
        correct_answers +=1


print("{}: You got {}/{} questions correct.".format(
    username, 
    correct_answers, 
    num_questions,

))

class_name = class_name + ".txt"    #creates a txt file called the class    that the user entered earlier on in the quiz.

file = open(class_name , 'a')   #These few lines open and then write the    username and the marks of the student into the txt file.
name = (username)
file.write(str(username + " : " ))  
file.write(str(correct_answers))
file.write('\n')    #This puts each different entry on a different line.
file.close()    #This closes the file once the infrmation has been written.
```

Comment: What is your code doing now? What is wrong with it?

Comment: You can use an update(list) method which you call everytime you get a new score. In the method, you get in parameter the score list and the new score, delete the oldest score and add the new one

Comment: The scores aren't saved in memory, they're saved in a text file on disk.

Comment: @abarnert: I missed that

Comment: @cdarke: Actually, with a `deque`, you don't need the `popleft` if you just set a `maxlen`. And together with `shelve`, that makes a perfect simple database for the OP's use…

Answer (score 1):

A much better solution would be to store the data in a different format that made everything easy. For example, if you used a [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) database that mapped each username to a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) of answers, the whole thing would be this simple:

```
with shelve.open(class_name) as db:
    answers = db.get(username, collections.deque(maxlen=3))
    answers.append(correct_answers)
    db[username] = answers
```

---

But if you can't change the data format, and you need to just append new lines to the end of a human-readable text file, then the only want to find out if there are already 3 answers is to read through every line in the file to see how many are already there. For example:

```
past_answers = []
with open(class_name) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        # rsplit(…,1) instead of split so users who call
        # themselves 'I Rock : 99999' can't cheat the system
        name, answers = line.rsplit(' : ', 1)
        if name == username:
            past_answers.append(i)
```

---

And if there were 3 past answers, you have to rewrite the file, skipping line #i. This is the really fun part; text files aren't random-access-editable, so the best you can do is either read it all into memory and write it back out, or copy it all to a temporary file and move it over the original. Like this:

```
excess_answers = set(past_answers[:-2])
if excess_answers:
    with open(class_name) as fin, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fout:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if i not in excess_answers:
                fout.write(line)
        os.replace(fout.name, fin)
```

That part is untested. And it requires Python 3.3+; if you have an earlier version and are on Mac or Linux you can just use `os.rename` instead of `replace`, but if you're on Windows… you need to do some research, because it's ugly and no fun.

---

And now, you can finally just append the new answer, as you're already doing.

Comment: Plus one for suggesting `shelve`

Comment: @cdarke: Moved the `shelve` part to the top, and stole your `deque` idea.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  I hadn't thought of using maxlen.  This is why I like stackoverflow.